# Is SSLv3 disabled on my Apache 2.4.9 (Win32?)

Tags: php, apache, ssl, apache2.4, poodle-attack

I have Apache 2.4.9 running on windows Server 2008 R2.

```
SERVER_SOFTWARE                          Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 OpenSSL/1.0.1g 
SSL_PROTOCOL                             TLSv1.2 
Registered Stream Socket Transports      tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
```

I need to immediately disable SSLv3 to prevent [Poodle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE). TO do that I opened the file `\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf`

Then I added the following line of code to it

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

After saving the changes, I restarted Apache.

When came back up, I looked at the output of `phpinfo()` but I still can see the following

SSL_PROTOCOL                             TLSv1.2 
Registered Stream Socket Transports      tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls

Is the `phpinfo()` where I check to see if the SSLv3 and SSLv2 are disabled or not?

Here are more methods I have done to ensure I am doing this correctly.
I tried adding this line instead of the other command (ie. 
`SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3`)

```
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1.2
```

I even tried to searching for any file that contains the word "SSLProtocol" inside Apache24 directory like so

```
C:\Apache24>findstr /s /i /p "SSLProtocol" *.*
```

this only found 2 files

1. httpd-ssl.conf
2. CHANGES.txt

How to check if SSLv3 is disabled or not on my server? 
If It is not disabled yet, how to properly disable it?

Answer (score 0):

`SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3` should disable SSLv3 protocol in your Apache installation.[For reference](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-disabling-ssl-v3.htm).
 I would not be sure about `phpinfo()` however if you want to see the enabled protocols on your site. [Browse here](https://www.digicert.com/help/) and enter your site address.Found this [post here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70733/how-do-i-use-openssl-s-client-to-test-for-absence-of-sslv3-support) . You can user `openssl` as well to check absence of SSLv3. Use below command to see what SSL protocols are enabled

> openssl s_client -connect {SERVER_IP/DNS_NAME}:443

To see other [promising tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssl+diagnose+tools&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&q=ssl+diagnostics+tools) you can Google and give it a try.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3` should have disabled SSL3 in Apache. You can check this (and other settings) at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html